# How to maintain the same ASP session during a redirect to SSL?

Tags: http, session, ssl, asp-classic, e-commerce

I have a shopping cart website running classic ASP that needs help during the checkout process.  When a user is ready to checkout, they are redirected to an SSL version of the site.

```
Response.Redirect "https://example.com/beginCheckoutProcess.asp"
```

When the jump occurs, the customer starts a new session when they arrive at the SSL version of the site.  This means that the contents of their cart are lost, leaving them with a terrible experience on the site.

Is there a way to maintain the same ASP session across the jump to SSL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you keep the subdomain same it'll just work.

Comment: It looks like that was the case.  Users were coming to our site without a www subdomain, and we were redirecting them to a hardcoded www subdomain SSL version of the site.

Thanks!

Comment: welcome :), For the sake of security take a look at "secure cookies". Depends on the application you might want to implement that, so you can secure your SSL session.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a cookie and storing it on both ends? Then you can recreate the session on the other end.